# Reloading groups from Glassfish using FlexibleJDBCRealm

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, jdbcrealm

I am using `FlexibleJDBCRealm` for authentication in my Glassfish application. Since it provides the flexibility to change groups on-the-fly by just assigning them in the database, it would be amazing if the updated groups could be effective right after assignment, i. e. without the need to logout and login again.

Is there a way to force Glassfish to reload the associated groups in any way? Or disable this caching behaviour altogether?

Update: Probably there is a way to use a `Filter` to reload those? Invalidating a `Session`doesn't seem feasible, though.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.